# How can I add a grid of shapes to a slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a class project at the moment and I'm having some trouble with the front-end part of it.

What I'm trying to do is implement a grid of hexagonal like shapes (I'm using [this](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons) example by web-tiki), that works exactly as I want when resizing the screen.

I want to put this grid in a carousel-like div, that adds a page with the same number of items when resizing, instead of stacking them underneath, thus taking up more space downwards.

I've been through a lot of research, but none of the examples given seemed to fit my case. Can anybody give me an insight on how to do that?

**Edit:  Based on Rustyjim's comment, I actually edited the carousel's js file to fit my needs, so consider the issue solved. Thanks for the responses!**

Comment: How do you want to make the hexagons? If you are fine with using an image (SVG or a normal bitmap), then using CSS grid to make a responsive grid of items should work for this. Learn more about CSS grid [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Comment: The thing is, the grid included in the link I'm referencing works perfectly for me, I just need to transfer excess items to a new carousel slide, based on the screen size. Let's say I have 5-4-5 items (total 14) on a laptop and bigger screen, and only 2-1-2 (total 5) on a mobile screen, having the extra items transferred to new slides.

Comment: Can you share the code maybe of the carousel you use? Then I believe someone can improve javascript to make this work, hope it helps.